# TFS Branching an incomplete version

Tags: branching, team-foundation-server, software-patches

I am working on an application and it is at a point where I need to wait for an API to be delivered to complete it. It's almost there but not quite finished.

My manager has told me he wants me to start working on 1.1 while we wait. When the API arrives, we will finish 1.0 and go through the release process. My usual branching strategy won't work here.

Usually, I would do releases from the trunk and have 1.0, 1.1 etc as branches. After each version, you merge to the trunk and release from there.

I need to consider that there will be more work done to version 1.0 even after the 1.1 branch is created. So any 1.0 work will also need to be in 1.1. Is there a way to branch from 1.0 and merge to both 1.0 and 1.1? I suppose it would be the same problem if there were bugs to patch in the future, would you manually copy the work over to 1.1 from 1.0 (that sounds wrong) or is there a mechanism for this?

Comment: Could you use Feature Flags for the new work, so that you keep your single branch 1.0? It would complicate work initially, but save you time later.

Comment: I will read up on feature flags, thanks for the tip.